# Call the php function using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a editor embeded in the html page

```
<div id="editor">
Problem Statement goes here&hellip;
</div>
```

I basically want to store the contents written in editor to a file(preferably in rich text format). I used a script (given below) for storing the contents in a string.(This I used by referring to [HTML div text to save and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745712/html-div-text-to-save-and-display) )

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> 
     var StoreEditorContent;  //declare a variable to save Content

      document.getElementById('save').addEventListener("click", SaveText);  // adding event listner for onclick for Saving text

    function SaveText(){

       StoreEditorContent = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML; // Save the Content into 
       document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = ""; // to blank the editor Content
       window.onload = function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "submit_request.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function writeMsg(StoreEditorContent){
                       //Not sure if this part is right.
                    }
                });   
        }
    }

    </script>
```

This of course is storing in the contents in a string `StoreEditorContent`. I now want to pass this string to a php function which will write this(`StoreEditorContent`) to a file.The php file that contains function to write is given below

```
<?php

function writeMsg($msg){
    $file = "myfile.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $msg);
}
?>
```

I know I need to use ajax here, but cannot figure out how? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The success callback function in the ajax call is for what you want to do on the frontend if the request succeeds. If you don't need to do anything, then just don't include it. In your case, it would make sense to put the piece where you empty the editor inside of here because you only want to empty the editor when your request has succeeded. Otherwise, the user loses all the contents even if the request fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a `data:` option to `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "submit_request.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { content: StoreEditorContent },
    success: function (response) {
        // Do something with the response sent from PHP
    }
});
```

Then your PHP can do:

```
writeMsg($_POST['content']);
```

You should use `POST` rather than `GET` for large requests because the limit on `GET` parameters is relatively small.

Comment: Should this be a post request rather than a get request?

Comment: @stefvhuynh Yes it should mate.