# How to get all value from ACE Editor using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, ace-editor

I used `ACE Editor`. I want to get all value from `ACE Editor` using `PHP`. How can i get?

I wrote `JQuery Ajax` code

```
 $('#save').click(function(){
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            var code = editor.getSession().getDocument().getValue();
                  $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "data.php",
                       data: {'code':code},
                       success: function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                       }
                     });
        });
```

When this code work, not all the code comes, what can i do? without `getlValue()` or `getSession()`

thanks regards

Comment: Does this answers help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963855/how-do-i-get-value-from-ace-editor?

Comment: i seen this answers but  it didn't work for me. For this reason i opened new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.

That's like

```
$('#save').click(function(){
            var editor = ace.edit("codeArea");
            var code = editor.getSession().getValue();
                  $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "data.php",
                       data: {'code':code},
                       success: function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                       }
                     });
        });
```

all you have to do `ace.edit('codeArea');` not `'editor'`

Comment: You probably need to edit your question to be more useful to other people, now it simply says that you had mixed up dom node ids, but that is not what title of the post says. Also you can simply use `editor.getValue();`